# Unknown way of dealing with Arrays in C

Tags: c

```
*--p = "0123456789abcdef"[num % 2];
```

Hello, I was reading some code and saw this line. I am learning C currently and I don't understand why there is a String infront of the [num % 2].

If you need a context, you can read the whole method here:

```
char * toBin(unsigned int num)
{
    static char retbuf[33];
    int i = 0;
    for (; i < 33; i++)
    {
        retbuf[i] = '0';
    }
    char *p;
    p = &retbuf[sizeof (retbuf) - 1];
    *p = '\0';
    do
    {
        *--p = "0123456789abcdef"[num % 2];
        num /= 2;
    }
    while (num != 0);
    return retbuf;
}
```

I know what the method is doing: It is converting a int number to its binary form. I just don't understand the first mentioned line. I know that it is somehow putting the bits from the (second) last position of the array in the retbuf, and I also understand why it uses num % 2 in order to get the 0's and 1's. But I just don't get why there is a string infront.

Comment: `array[index]` -> `element` ...

Comment: Thanks Karoly, I know this concept. But here we have a string infront of [...] and not a name of an array.

Comment: It seems to me that it would work just the same with `"01"`[num%2] as it only uses the first 2 characters of the array. the entire "01..ef" is probably from similar function that converted the hex

Comment: @IgalS. That makes sense. I just couldn't see it. Thank you.

Comment: @DennisvonEich: think of a string as an array of characters.

Comment: this function is terrible. it always return a static block of memory, which is super error prone. since you have no idea when your return value will be voided implicitly.

Comment: in C, when referencing an array by name, the result is address of the array.  The literal "0123456789abcdef" is an array with no name.  referencing it results in the address of the array.

Comment: the `for` loop does not add any functionality to the function so should be completely removed.  a 'static' variable is so the variable contents will be available on the execution of the function.  strongly suggest using malloc() instead of a static variable.  the code wastes memory by the static declaration and by the oversized literal array declaration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Using string is equivalent to using an array. In this specific case the following would be sufficient:

```
*--p = "01"[num % 2];
```

Since only the first 2 positions of the array is in use. I assume that the entire string "01...ef" is from a similar function that converted to hex.

Comment: This is exactly the information I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Keep in mind that in  C a String is just a character array. So

```
*--p = "0123456789abcdef"[num % 2];
```

is the same as if you had

```
char digits[] = "0123456789abcdef";
....
*--p = digits[num % 2];
```

and like others have alrady pointed out, `*--p` will be set to `'0'` or `'1'` depending on `num` being even or odd

Answer (score 3):

In C, a constant string points to the memory location of its first element;

array name without square brackets also points to the address of the first element of the array. So elements in a constant string can be accessed in the same way as we do with array.

See the example below

```
char arr[10] = "Hello";

printf("%c %c", arr[4], "Hello"[4]);
```

It will print the charecter 'o' 2 times.
Hope you understood.

Answer (score 2):

For the record, just in case someone stumbles over this question in the future, the function posted is horrible, don't use it. A proper way to implement this algorithm would be something like this:

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>

char* uint32_to_binstr (uint32_t num, char buf[32+1]);

static size_t get_bin_digits (uint32_t i);

int main(void)
{
  char str[32+1];

  printf("%u\t-> %s\n",     0, uint32_to_binstr(    0, str));
  printf("%u\t-> %s\n",     2, uint32_to_binstr(    2, str));
  printf("%u\t-> %s\n",    15, uint32_to_binstr(   15, str));
  printf("%u\t-> %s\n",   255, uint32_to_binstr(  255, str));
  printf("%u\t-> %s\n", 12345, uint32_to_binstr(12345, str));
}

char* uint32_to_binstr (uint32_t num, char buf[32+1])
{
  const uint32_t BASE = 2;

  // count the number of binary digits in advance, to get a left-aligned string:
  size_t digits = get_bin_digits(num); 
  size_t i;

  for(i=0; i<digits; i++)
  {
    char ch = num % BASE + '0';
    buf[digits-i-1] = ch; // have to write string from right to left
    num /= BASE;
  }

  buf[i] = '\0';
  return buf;
}

static size_t get_bin_digits (uint32_t i)
{
  size_t digits = 0;

  if(i==0)
  {
    return 1;
  }

  for(; i>0; i>>=1)
  {
    digits++;
  }

  return digits;
}
```

Output:

```
0       -> 0
2       -> 10
15      -> 1111
255     -> 11111111
12345   -> 11000000111001
```

Comment: And yes, this doesn't exactly answer the question, but there has to be a call for sanity somewhere in this thread, or newbies finding it in the future might start writing code like the one posted in the question.

Comment: It is an assignment of a university. Maybe this function makes sense in the given context?

Comment: @DennisvonEich What context? Are they teaching you how to not write C code? To be specific, the original function has the following problems: returning a pointer to a local static variable is always dangerous: it will cause order of evaluation issues if the same function is called several times in the same expression and it is not re-entrant, meaning it will cause crashes in multi-threaded applications. Furthermore, initializing the buffer to "all zeroes" is inelegant and probably not what you want in most cases. Furthermore, the down-counting pointer is ugly and hard to read. ->

Comment: Furthermore, the string literal with all numbers doesn't make sense, as the function only handles binary and not variable bases. `"0123456789abcdef"[num % 2]` is particularly ugly. And because the buffer is already initialized, the code ends up writing to the same memory location twice. Apart from the function, `get_bin_digits`, which I didn't bother optimizing manually, my code should probably also run a bit faster, even though it has the left-align feature that the other code lacks. Also, the original code is non-portable, since it assumes that int is 32 bits.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you have hexa string there, but what it is doing is dividing the int num by 2 if it's even `n%2 = 0` so the element 0 of the string will be picked ('0') if it's odd `n%2 = 1` so it will pick element 1 of the array ('1'). In the loop the pointer `p` goes backwards in the retbuff to place each char ('0' or '1') in order

It's a really weird way of doing this